# How to load data from an URL using CakePHP

Tags: php, rest, api, cakephp

Probably it is repeat of question but I haven't find any answers anywhere.

I am trying to load data from an URL in cake php. Basically it is an API call. My codes are seating inside the vendor folder and my URL is as follows:

```
 /test.php?n=Class&v=method
```

the complete URL will be
    localhost/test.php?n=Class&v=method

I tried file_get_contents ($url), seems like not working.

any ideas? or is there any other cakephp way of loading this data. Thanks

Comment: that file `test.php` contains some html or raw data or it's having functions and class?

Comment: it contains routes to classes and methods, basically this is working as index.php to call the method inside the class